# Store Calculations on MongooseDB?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, mongoose

I am working with the MERN stack. I am developing an application where a user enters for eg 4 numbers and I should store the combinations of the 4 numbers and store them on the database without showing it to the user. The problem I have is how to store the combinations that I calculated on the DB, I don't know where to start from. Anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this technique

```
let array = [45, 23, 13, 67];
let results = [];

// Since you only want pairs, there's no reason
// to iterate over the last element directly
for (let i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
  // This is where you'll capture that last value
  for (let j = i + 1; j < array.length; j++) {
    results.push(`${array[i]} ${array[j]}`);
  }
}
console.log(results); // ["45 23", "45 13", "45 67", "23 13", "23 67", "13 67"]
```

you can store the array as a combination of 4 numbers.